# How change http on change select?

Tags: angularjs, http, select

I want to build a category filter in my angular application. I have a select option dropdown. If I select an other category I want to load an other http request. Each category have a different URL to call.

**My controller:**

```
.controller('activiteitenCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

if(selectCategory == 1){
$scope.groep = "http://www.example.com/?id=1";
}
if(selectCategory == 2){
$scope.groep = "http://www.example.com/?id=2";
} 
else{
$scope.groep = "http://www.example.com/?id=3";
}

$scope.loadData = function () {
        $http.get($scope.groep, {cache:false})
        .success(function(data) {$scope.activiteiten = data.posts; });
}

    $scope.loadData();


})
```

**My template:**

```
        <select>
      <option value="0">Recent</option>
      <option value="1">Groep 1</option>
      <option value="2">Groep 2</option>
      <option value="3">Groep 3</option>
      <option value="4">Groep 4</option>
      <option value="5">Groep 5</option>
      <option value="6">Groep 6</option>
      <option value="7">Groep 7</option>
      <option value="8">Groep 8</option>


    </select>
```

I tried ng click but that's not working. how i get the value of the select menu in the controller and reload the data with the loadData() function? so that the items form te selected category appear in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should be something like this:

```
   <select ng-model="selectCategory" ng-change="selected()">
  <option value="0">Recent</option>
  <option value="1">Groep 1</option>
  <option value="2">Groep 2</option>
  <option value="3">Groep 3</option>
  <option value="4">Groep 4</option>
  <option value="5">Groep 5</option>
  <option value="6">Groep 6</option>
  <option value="7">Groep 7</option>
  <option value="8">Groep 8</option>


</select>
```

And in your controller you need to create the callback function that is executed when the value of the select box changes:

```
$scope.selected = function() {
    if($scope.selectCategory == "1"){
        $scope.groep = "http://www.example.com/?id=1";
    }
    if($scope.selectCategory == "2"){
        $scope.groep = "http://www.example.com/?id=2";
    } 
    else{
        $scope.groep = "http://www.example.com/?id=3";
    }
    $scope.loadData();
}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/4pBvvL4MUn09HrjwSPtC?p=preview

Comment: Thanx, that was wat i'm looking for. Only problem is only the else executes the if  functions don't recognize that they match with the value from select, any suggestions?

Comment: @MaartenHeideman Try adding `alert($scope.selectCategory);` or `console.log($scope.selectCategory);`  inside `$scope.selected()` - It will show you the actual value

Comment: i did and when i select an option it returns undefined

Comment: @MaartenHeideman - I added a plunker example to my answer. Let me know if it helps